# Well formed query suggestions

Tags: data-structures, indexing, redis, elasticsearch

I am developing an autocomplete feature in which i intend to show query suggestions something like this:

students who live in {City_name} [ City_name could contain values from list of cities ]

**example_type 1 :**

> students who live in New...

[ following query suggestions should pop-up ] :

> students who live in ***New york***
>   students who live in ***New
>   Jersey***

*(Looking up different entities [here cities, sports (eg: "students who play basketball" etc...]. )*

**example_type 2:**

> students who live in New york and play ba...

[ following query suggestions should pop-up ] :

> students who live in New York **and**  play ***basketball***
>   students who
>   live in New York **and** play ***baseball***
>    etc..

I have tried building basic autocomplete on entities index using ElasticSearch, which is gisted [here](https://gist.github.com/dipeshtech/6138796).
(In my case, the child/entities index is dumped using a river-plugin.) I have naively checked on Nested Types and Parent / Child relationship but was not able to exactly figure out whether its the right fit for my requirement.

I am not sure on how to index these (parent) phrases alongwith 
child index to enable autocomplete search and generate possible suggest trees by querying/searching a single index.

It would be great if i can get some help to solve this kind of problem. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is elastic search is not serving you purpose? I have started learning Big data components and its good that you asked it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd index phrases such as:

```
live in New york
live in New Jersey
play basketball
play baseball
```

And then do some work client side to figure out you've started a new section in the query, and then only send the letters in the new section to ES for typeahead completion.

This will take some work on the front end, but this i could see working. The other alternative being indexing every possible variation on a query phrase for typeahead, but I highly doubt that's viable.